# IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1 not compatible with Android SDK tools r12?

Tags: android, sdk, intellij-idea

I just updated to the latest Android SDK Tools, r12.
Now compiling of my current project fails by

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: Lorg/anddev/andengine/audio/BaseAudioEntity;

<= The library is definitely added only once - so this must be a compiling problem.

It also fails finding some standard android themes:

> ...\res\values\styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item:
>   No resource found that matches the given name
>   '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Inverse'.

The paths to the SDK and other included libraries are correct.

Anyone with same issues?
Thank you!

Comment: This issue seems to fit my problem:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18659

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer and mark it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got the compiling issue fixed - this happened because I included an external library (AndEngine) which sources already were existent in the /out folder. After clearing the folder's contents the project compiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/anddev/andengine/audio/BaseAudioEntity;"

Most probably there are AndEngine and some extension jars build so, that extension include classes of andengine. To resolve this issue -> exclude andengine src during rebuilding extensions (uncheck folder in export window).